# Jquery validation plugin - check if email exists

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I'm trying to check on email field blur, if the email already exists in db. My code is now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Validation
        $("#soutez").validate({
            rules: {
                   email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: "check-email.php",
                },

            },
            messages:{
                email:'Email address exists.'
            },
            onkeyup: false,
            onblur: true,
      });

     });
</script>
```

And the php code is

```
$email= $_GET['email'];
echo $email;
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
global $wpdb;

$email_exists = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT COUNT(*) as count from reg_form_new WHERE email = "'.$email.'"');

if ( $email_exists->count == 0 ) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; }

exit; }
```

The php code returns true/false correctly, but for some reason it doesn't work with the jQuery script. Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: is not that easy because e.g johndoe@gmail.com, johnDoe@gmail.com, john.doe@gmail.com, j.o.h.n.d.o.e@gmail.com, etc... are all the same email

Comment: what does the echo $email do in the line 2 of PHP code ?

Comment: just tested if I get the email...

Comment: Wouldn't the echo $email line make the return "<email address>true" instead of just "true"

Comment: I tried return true, which doesn't work neither..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to echo exactly the string `'true'` and nothing else if you want it to be allowed through.  Anything else (`'false'`,`null`,`undefined`, or any string) will be interpreted as invalid and if there is a string, that string will be displayed.

So check carefully that your php script is printing out only `'true'` or `'false'` for now.  The script as you've shown  it prints the email followed by `'true'` or `'false'`.  This will always be interpreted as `false`.

Read the documentation of the [remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid
>   elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid
>   elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is
>   already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.

Use Firebug or Chrome Inspector to verify that your response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Jquery, you can to adapt the working function to your need:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "check-email.php",
            type:'GET',
            /*you my specify dataType: 'json', for example ...*/
            data: $("#soutez").serialize(), //email input id 
            success: function(res) { 
                switch(res) {
                    case ('true'):
                        alert("true");  
                        break;

                    case ('false'):
                        alert('false');
                        break;
                                    // other cases...

                }
            } 

      });
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the jQuery validation plugin

Comment: What if the user disable the Javascript ?the best approach is to add a PHP validation, something like  :
 if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    echo "Email Not Valid ! ";

Comment: I of course do have PHP validation after the form submission. What I want is to inform the user that the email exists when filling the form.